# Print to PDF macro mysteriously stopped working

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros

Since approximately one week ago, my print macro stopped working. Here is what it looks like:

```
Function Create_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _ OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String Dim FileFormatstr As String Dim FName As Variant

'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
     & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

    If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
        'Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the pdf
        FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
        FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                              Title:="Create PDF")

        'If you cancel this dialog Exit the function
        If FName = False Then Exit Function
    Else
        FName = FixedFilePathName
    End If

    'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False we test if the PDF
    'already exist in the folder and Exit the function if that is True
    If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
        If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Exit Function
    End If

    'Now the file name is correct we Publish to PDF
    On Error Resume Next
    Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=FName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If Publish is Ok the function will return the file name
    If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Create_PDF = FName
End If

End Function
```

---

```
Sub SaveThisReport()

Dim MyFolder As String
Dim MyFile As String
Dim PDFname As String
Dim FileName As String

On Error Resume Next
MyFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator & "PDF Reports"
MkDir MyFolder
On Error GoTo 0

PDFname = ActiveSheet.Range("SelectedSchool").Value
MyFile = MyFolder & Application.PathSeparator & PDFname
FileName = Create_PDF(ActiveSheet.Range("ReportArea"), MyFile, True, False)
Range("A1").Select
```

The workbook containing the macro can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hTecZGc3npxcKzW_Hwu7KJ_AajQK-KOK/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: So what is the error message? What line does it fail on?

Comment: Write what error message you are getting, will help us to fix the issue.

Comment: Thanks for asking -- I am logged in now. I am having trouble making an error log. No error is created. Instead the cursor just goes to cell A1. Here is the file and to activate the macro, simply click on the CHALKBOARD PICTURE, which has the macro assigned to it.

Comment: Two notes to add:
1) The Cell, D2 in both worksheets is used as a PDF file name cell... the content gives the name of the pdf file to be created.

Comment: 2) The second worksheet has a pulldown menu in B2 that creates a unique pivot-table type page for each teacher. It used to print nicely so each teacher got a report. Not printing now ;-)

Your thoughts are appreciated: 
File can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hTecZGc3npxcKzW_Hwu7KJ_AajQK-KOK/view?usp=sharing

Comment: does C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\OFFICE12\EXP_PDF.DLL exist? - Have you checked? - I don't have such a file - The 12 will vary depending on which version you have - which is in Application.Version

Comment: OfficeTalk: Creating and Sending PDF Files from Excel 2007 and Excel 2010 mentions that this is no longer supported - so has this been mysteriously removed? That's not sarcastic my companies IT department changes configurations regularly with no communication.

Comment: I looked for EXP_PDF.DLL and found it.... and copied it to the desktop... What to do with it?

search-ms:displayname=Search%20Results%20in%20microsoft%20shared&crumb=filename%3A~<EXP_PDF.DLL%20OR%20System.Generic.String%3AEXP_PDF.DLL&crumb=location:C%3A%5CWindows.old%5CWINDOWS%5CSOFTWA~1%5CDownload%5C248AEE~1%5CAM056B~1.1%5CMICROS~3.MIC%5CMICROS~1.0_X%5Cvfs%5CPROGRA~1%5CMICROS~1

Comment: THIS WORKS (below) but how do I make so works for any user (See strDir)?

Sub PrintToPDF_M1()
    
Dim strDir As String
    strDir = "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\PDF Reports\"
    
    If Dir(strDir, vbDirectory) = "" Then
        MkDir strDir
    End If
    
    Range("ReportAreaM1").Select
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "C:\Users\Jonathan\Desktop\PDF Reports\" & Range("SelectedSchool_M1").Value & ".pdf", Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= _
        False
End Sub

Comment: THE FOLLOWING IS THE LINK TO THE FIXED FILE. Also, I added the line  
    Range("A1").Select  
  
as the last line of the SUB so that after it runs the cursor is focused on the cell A1. My only need now is to make this portable so I can use it on a computer where the user is not "Jonathan" or perhaps windows moved the desktop to a new place. Ideas???  
  
`**Link to Almost-Finished-File**<https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kQq0dKpAgd0j2JnA5jrG3NLjowExxq1B/view?usp=sharing>`

Answer (score 0):

The SaveThisReport() section of your VBA code in its current state, is useless as,

- You've not defined the variable **"SelectedSchool"** anywhere in your code.

  - Since **PDFname** and **SelectedSchool** are virtually doing the same thing it's redundant.
- You've not defined the variable **"ReportArea"** anywhere in your code.

In the <s>`FileName = Create_PDF(ActiveSheet.Range("ReportArea"), MyFile, True, False)`</s> the object is the ActiveSheet so `FileName = Create_PDF(ActiveSheet, MyFile, True, False)` is sufficient.

---

**Try this**

```
Sub SaveThisReport()

    Dim MyFolder As String
    Dim MyFile As String
    Dim PDFname As String
    Dim FileName As String
    Dim ReportArea As String

    'Initialise your pdfname variable
    'From your comment you've identified D2 as the file name.
    PDFname = ActiveSheet.Range("D2").Value 

    On Error Resume Next
        MyFolder = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").SpecialFolders("Desktop") & Application.PathSeparator & "PDF Reports"
        MkDir MyFolder
    On Error GoTo 0

    MyFile = MyFolder & Application.PathSeparator & PDFname
    FileName = Create_PDF(ActiveSheet, MyFile, True, False)
    Range("A1").Select

End Sub
```

**Note**: ActiveSheet refers to the currently active sheet only! So if you're trying to use this on another sheet it will reference "D2" in that current sheet. would be best to identify which specific sheet has the information you need like `PDFname = Sheets("YOURSHEETNAMEHERE").Range("D2").Value`.

**Additional Note**: Make sure when you're [copying and pasting](https://medium.freecodecamp.org/the-benefits-of-typing-instead-of-copying-54ed734ad849) the above code that you are changing the function name of **Create_PDF** to reference the correct function name like below.

```
Function Create_PDF(Myvar As Object, FixedFilePathName As String, _
                OverwriteIfFileExist As Boolean, OpenPDFAfterPublish As Boolean) As String
Dim FileFormatstr As String
Dim FName As Variant

'Test If the Microsoft Add-in is installed
If Dir(Environ("commonprogramfiles") & "\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE" _
     & Format(Val(Application.Version), "00") & "\EXP_PDF.DLL") <> "" Then

    If FixedFilePathName = "" Then
        'Open the GetSaveAsFilename dialog to enter a file name for the pdf
        FileFormatstr = "PDF Files (*.pdf), *.pdf"
        FName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename("", filefilter:=FileFormatstr, _
                                              Title:="Create PDF")

        'If you cancel this dialog Exit the function
        If FName = False Then Exit Function
    Else
        FName = FixedFilePathName
    End If

    'If OverwriteIfFileExist = False we test if the PDF
    'already exist in the folder and Exit the function if that is True
    If OverwriteIfFileExist = False Then
        If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Exit Function
    End If

    'Now the file name is correct we Publish to PDF
    On Error Resume Next
    Myvar.ExportAsFixedFormat _
            Type:=xlTypePDF, _
            FileName:=FName, _
            Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
            IncludeDocProperties:=True, _
            IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
            OpenAfterPublish:=OpenPDFAfterPublish
    On Error GoTo 0

    'If Publish is Ok the function will return the file name
    If Dir(FName) <> "" Then Create_PDF = FName
End If
End Function
```

Comment: I tried the above solution and it failed on line 15 where it says "Create_PDF"

SO I DID SOME RESEARCH AND CREATED A WORKING SOLUTION, BUT WITH ONE NEW QUESTION.

Comment: **YOU HAVE TO DO MORE THAN JUST COPY PASTE SNIPPETS OF CODE FROM THE INTERNET!** Make sure your **Create_PDF** function exist. Because I renamed YOUR **Create_PDF_M1** to **Create_PDF** when I delete all the other unnecessary code for my tests, that is why **SaveThisReport** is not **SaveThisReport_M1** in my answer!

Comment: Thanks for this assistance. See above comment <https://superuser.com/questions/1332520/print-to-pdf-macro-mysteriously-stopped-working#comment1994441_1332520> because everything works except making general folder for "any user" not just me. Thanks in advance for input.

Comment: @JonathanDoll Please ask a new question as your code & question has completely changed. Please note superuser is designed for [1 specific question with 1 specific answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).